# Zend Framework 2 translate form errors doesnt work

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2, zend-translate

I spent all night trying to figure out why this code doesn't work

```php
$inputFilter = new InputFilter();
$factory = new InputFactory();

$translator = new \Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator();
//Copy of file found in resources/languages/es/Zend_Validate.php
$translator->addTranslationFile('phparray', './module/Product/language/zend_validate.php');

$inputFilter->add(
    $factory->createInput(
        array(
            'name' => 'idpro',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'Int'),
            ),
        )
    )
);

$inputFilter->add(
    $factory->createInput(
        array(
            'name' => 'nompro',
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                    'options' => array(
                        'translator' => $translator
                    )
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

I've installed php5-intl and enabled it in the php.ini

but it doesnt work i get the same message *Value is required and can't be empty* but it should be the translated one ...

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did to make Form Errors Translate properly:

module.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory'
        )
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'        => 'gettext',
                'base_dir'    => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'     => '%s.mo',
                'text_domain' => 'admin'
            ),
            array(
                'type'        => 'phparray',
                'base_dir'    => __DIR__ . '/../resources/languages',
                'pattern'     => '/%s/Zend_Validate.php',
                'text_domain' => 'default'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I think this is the best way to configure that. Thanks a lot to @Diemuzi

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the translator by this way.

Use instead this static method :

```
\Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator, 'default');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah i see something like that but sorry i'm just learning zend i'm noob could you say me please where to put that code you give me ....... thanks ...

Comment: For your test, you can put it just after having instantiate your translator.

But it should be better in the Module.php of application module in order to load the validation's translations for all modules.